# Sum values without aliases correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a query that is returning everything correctly except for some slight inconsistencies on one of my total columns (sum) and I can't figure out why it's happening or a better way to approach it.

Here's the section of the query in question:

```
SELECT 
 c.extension 
,RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID 
 , sum(Duration)  -- seconds
, round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) -- minutes
, sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0))  -- outbound
, sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0) and ANSWERED = 1) -- inbound
, sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1))  -- missed
, count(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) + count(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0))   -- as total_calls 
, now()
, b.ts 
FROM cdrdb.session a
INNER JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
   ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
INNER join cdrdb.mxuser c
   ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
   WHERE b.ts BETWEEN curdate() - interval 30 day and curdate()
AND c.extension IN (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)
group by DATE(b.ts),c.extension;
```

And here are the first few results:

[image]

The total calls column should add inbound, outbound and missed calls. You can see that most of the time, the total is correct, but especially in the first and third row, it is off. If I give the formulas `AS` aliases and try to sum the aliases, it says the column doesn't exist.

Is there something I"m missing that's causing the inconsistency and more importantly, is there a more direct way I can sum those 3 columns/values?

Comment: use `sum(LEGTYPE1 = 1) + sum(LEGTYPE1 = 2)` for total calls and also add `RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID` in `group by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the total calls as the sum of inbound, outbound, and missed calls, yet in your query you only included 2 of these 3 terms:

```
count(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) + count(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0))
```

In addition, using `COUNT` there is probably not what you intended.  This would just count the number of records, assuming all values are not `NULL`.  Instead, just sum the three types of call sums using `SUM`:

Use `SUM`, not `COUNT`, when computing the total calls:

```
SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound
SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 2, 1, 0) AND ANSWERED = 1) +  -- inbound
SUM(IF(Answered = 1, 0, 1)) AS total_calls      -- missed
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to use `SUM` instead of `COUNT` on `total_calls`.
Second, if you want to use aliases you need to wrap it all in another `SELECT` like this:

```
SELECT 
*,
(t.inbound + t.outbound) total_calls
FROM
(SELECT
    c.extension,
    RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID, 
    sum(Duration) seconds, 
    round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) minutes,
    sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) outbound, 
    sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0) and ANSWERED = 1) inbound,
    sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) missed,
    now(),
    b.ts 
    FROM cdrdb.session a
        INNER JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
        ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
        INNER join cdrdb.mxuser c
        ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
    WHERE b.ts BETWEEN curdate() - interval 30 day and curdate()
    AND c.extension IN (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)
    GROUP BY DATE(b.ts),c.extension) t;
```